# Angular direct setting of property can't access in component html

Tags: angular

example in component.ts:

```
tmptotal:number;
this.tmptotal=this.orderService.orderTotal;
```

in component.html:

```
{{tmptotal}}
```

the above doesn't work.

but if I do like in component.ts:

```
totalPrice(){
    this.tmptotal=this.orderService.orderTotal;
    return this.tmptotal;
}
```

and component.html

```
{{totalprice()}}
```

This works.
What is wrong with the first example. I am new to Angular, am not able to make out why.

Comment: Where do you call this code in the first example?

Comment: in the constructor. this line is in constructor - `this.tmptotal=this.orderService.orderTotal;`

Comment: Seems like `orderService` doesn't have the data yet

Answer (score 0):

Any code initialization within a component is recommended to be handled in `OnInit` lifecycle hook, not the constructor. I suggest the following approach:

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  tmptotal: number;
  
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tmptotal = this.orderService.orderTotal;
  }
}
```

**template**

```html
<p>{{ tmptotal }}</p>
```